# Batch file to execute python script

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file to execute a python script and not having much luck. I tried the following:

```
@echo off
SET path C:\"Program Files\python37\python.exe"
C:\"projects\systemcheck.py -c systems.csv"
```

but get the following error:

```
C:\projects>nexus-script.bat Environment variable path C:\"Program
Files\python37\python.exe" not defined 'C:\"projects\systemcheck.py -c
systems.csv"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Try fixing your paths: `SET path "C:\Program Files\python37\python.exe"` and `python C:\projects\systemcheck.py -c systems.csv`

Comment: 1. The [`set`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) syntax is wrong, it is `set var=value`. 2. [`Path`](https://ss64.com/nt/path.html) is a system variable, so you should not overwrite it...

Answer (score 0):

It may be easiest to specify the full path to the Python executable. That way you don't have to worry about the PATH environment variable.

```
@echo off                                                                                                                                                                   
"C:\Program Files\python37\python.exe" C:\projects\systemcheck.py -c systems.csv
```

If you absolutely need to set the PATH environment variable, you would do it like this:

```
@echo off                                                                                                                                                                   
SET "PATH=C:\Program Files\python37;%PATH%"
python C:\projects\systemcheck.py -c systems.csv
```

Note that the path to the Python folder goes before the previous contents of PATH; this ensures that that is the Python that gets run if you have multiple Python installations on you computer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to have your FULL path in quotes. Example: SET path to **"C:\Program Files\python37\python.exe"**
2. You don't need to SET the path, you can do what Jack mentioned in a past comment.